# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos k}{2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I can tell that the series converges: define
$$a_k:=\left|\frac{\cos k}{2^k}\right|.$$
Then $0\leq a_k\leq \frac{1}{2^k}$. As
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$$
converges, then so does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$, and hence so does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos k}{2^k}$.

But that's not what the question is asking for. How can I find what it actually converges to?

I've tried rewriting it as 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ik}+e^{-ik}}{2^{k+1}},$$
but can't see how that helps.

Comment: Hint: Use $2^{k+1}=e^{\ln(2)(k+1)}$ and the geometric series.

Comment: That helps because you are left with geometric series, whose sums you are supposed to be able to evaluate.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt No idea how transforming $2^{k+1}$ as you suggest, can help.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think about that. Got it now, thanks @Did!

Comment: Your sum is now basically $\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left((e^i/2)^k+(e^{-i}/2)^k\right)$. Now, break the sum into two parts and sum the geometric series.

Comment: Personally, I would've written$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(k)}{2^k}=\Re\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty(e^i/2)^k\right]$$Just to be a bit shorter.

Comment: For a shortcut, use $\cos x=\Re(e^{ix})$ for every real number $x$, rather than $\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n = -\dfrac{r}{r-1}$ whenever $|r| <1$

Now we need to eval $\Re \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{n i}}{2^n}= \dfrac{e^{n i}}{e^{n \ln 2}} = e^{n(i-\ln 2)} = (e^{i-\ln 2})^n$.

We need to check that $\left\lvert{e^{i-\ln 2}}\right\rvert=\dfrac{1}{2} <1$ and the summation will be equal to $-\dfrac{r}{r-1}$ such that $r = e^{i-\ln 2}$.

We arrive at $-\dfrac{e^{i}/2}{e^{i}/2-1}$ which is just $\dfrac{e^i}{2-e^i}$

Which is $\dfrac{\cos (1)+i \sin (1)}{2-i \sin (1)-\cos (1)}$

We need to evaluate the value

$$\begin{align}
\Re\dfrac{\cos (1)+i \sin (1)}{2-i \sin (1)-\cos (1)} & = & \Re \dfrac{(\cos (1)+i \sin (1)) (2-\cos (1)+i \sin (1))}{(2-\cos (1)-i \sin (1))
   (2-\cos (1)+i \sin (1))} \\[2ex] & = & \dfrac{(2-\cos (1)) \cos (1)}{\sin ^2(1)+(2-\cos (1))^2}-\dfrac{\sin ^2(1)}{\sin^2(1)+(2-\cos (1))^2} 
\end{align}$$

Further manipulating using trigonometric identities one can arrive at $\dfrac{1-2 \cos (1)}{4 \cos (1)-5} \approx 0.028394$